Which is correct "Had not have any waffles in ages" or "have not had any waffles in ages"?
My neighbor mentioned waffles in a recent conversation. I replied: Hmmm . .. waffles. Good idea. I had not have any waffles in ages. I now believe the sequence is wrong. Should it not rather be: "I have not had any waffles in ages. Or is this version wrong as well?

Had (or have, or had not, or having) cannot govern a base-form verb like "have": it must govern the pp "had".
[This is have as the perfect auxiliary, of course. There is a different use of have with an expressed agent and the base form, meaning "cause or allow", as in I had them make me a cake or I wouldn't have you go hungry.]

"I had not had any waffles in ages until my friend made me some last week."

The first version is incorrect, the second version is correct.

This is not an answer, it explains nothing.

@Mari-LouA it's not that much better than your comment, to be fair. I am writing this based on my first language - english, and this is a very obviously wrong one. If it were harder, I would leave it to the grammar experts.

My comment doesn't pretend to be an answer, it's an observation.  Please look at Colin Fine's answer, I don't think it's very clear for someone who knows nothing about grammar. Then again, this is a website for advanced speakers, ELL is for learners.

@Mari-LouA I am not sure if you meant this, but I can tell you that it definitely sounds wrong to a native speaker, with or without grammar expertise. Point taken though.
